# How do I move empty folders and files into a new folder?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, move, mkdir

How do I get the contents of a folder (including empty folders) to be moved (not copied) into a new folder excluding one folder?

I want to move the contents in the `Entity` folder into my newly created folder `2013\November Estimates` that is in each entity.

The folder layout is 2013\2 - November Projections\Fund Family (32 of them, plus other folder not concerned with)\Entity (600 different entities unique to each fund family)

This is the current layout for each entity:

```
    Entity_01
    Entity_01\2013
    Entity_01\2013\November Estimates
    Entity_01\entity.pdf
    Entity_01\entity.xls
    Entity_01\entity.doc
    Entity_01\PY folder
    Entity_01\Trash Folder
    Entity_01\2012
```

So all the files and folders are moved to `November Estimates` but the folder `2012` stays where it is (producing the following layout)

```
Entity_01
Entity_01\2013
Entity_01\2013\November Estimates
Entity_01\2013\November Estimates\entity.pdf
Entity_01\2013\November Estimates\entity.xls
Entity_01\2013\November Estimates\entity.doc
Entity_01\2013\November Estimates\PY folder
Entity_01\2013\November Estimates\Trash Folder
Entity_01\2012
```

Issues with the following command line:

```
 FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN (entitylist.txt) DO (
    pushd "%destdrive%:\%year%\%projections%\%%~a\%%~b\" && (
    for /d %%c in (*) do if /i not "%%c"=="2012" move "%%c" "%estimates%" 
    move *.* "%estimates%" 
    popd
)
     )
```

Complete BAT

```
@echo off
setlocal
SET "sourcedrive=Z"
SET "destdrive=C"
SET /a year=2013
SET "projections=2 - November Projections"
SET "Estimates=November Estimates"
SET "Yearend=Year End Filings"
DIR /b /ad "%sourcedrive%:\%year%\%projections%" >fundfamily.txt
start /wait "Fund Family" C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe "fundfamily.txt"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (fundfamily.txt) DO (
 MD "%destdrive%:\%year%\%projections%\%%~a"
 DIR /b /ad "%sourcedrive%:\%year%\%projections%\%%~a" >entitylist.txt
 start /wait "%%~a entities" C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe "entitylist.txt"
 FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN (entitylist.txt) DO MD "%destdrive%:\%year%\%projections%\%%~a\%%~b\%year%\%estimates%"
 FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN (entitylist.txt) DO MD "%destdrive%:\%year%\%projections%\%%~a\%%~b\%year%\%yearend%"
 FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN (entitylist.txt) DO MD "%destdrive%:\%year%\%projections%\%%~a\%%~b\2012"
 FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN (entitylist.txt) DO (
    pushd "%destdrive%:\%year%\%projections%\%%~a\%%~b\" && (
    for /d %%c in (*) do if /i not "%%c"=="2012" move "%%c" "%estimates%" 
    move *.* "%estimates%" 
    popd
    )
 )
)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move contents of folder into new folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20724181/move-contents-of-folder-into-new-folder)

Comment: /EXCLUDE is not a parameter of move command.

Comment: @mihai_mandis any suggestions on how I would go about fixing this? even without the EXCLUDE i still get an error and not the desired results

Comment: @KenWhite why are you even commenting on this if you aren't going to provide any insight, help or constructive feedback to the issue I encounter?

Comment: I don't follow your folder layout in your question, but to move a folder tree, except for one folder, can be done by `A)` moving the entire tree, `B)` creating the needed directory path, and `C)` moving the single folder back there.

Comment: @foxidrive, I just need to move the documents and folders at the bottom of the tree, the entity level, into a new folder that is being created at the bottom in the entity level. There are 600 different entities so manually doing this is quite tedious. This issue may come up again so I am trying to make this applicable to future needs.

Comment: Your description of the question could be improved.  Put in two areas with the complete paths of before and after for instance.

Comment: @foxidrive, Does the edit above with current and desired path help?

Comment: No, sorry, there isn't enough information about the entire task.  If you describe the whole task then you may get something which helps. Reading code that doesn't work is not useful, when there is poor information about what it is supposed to do and what it didn't do, and also knowing the whole folder structure.

Comment: @foxidrive, I had a worded description but was told to put the current results and desired results instead. but what i need to do is move EVERYTNING ( *.doc, *.xls, *pdf, folders, empty folders) into a new folder.  the structure is 2013 > "2 - November Projections" > 32 different Fund Family folders plus other folders ( I am only concerned with the fund families) > 600 different entity folders unique to each fund family > then this is where I am creating my new folders (each entity) and want all previous content in each folder moved into the new folder I created 2013\November Estimates

Comment: @foxidrive, I cannot get the syntax correct, and when do I it moves everything EXCEPT the folders that are currently there. I want to move all documents and the empty folders in each separate entity into a new folder being created in each entity.

Comment: @foxidrive, That is near perfect to the layout and desired results. Please see my edits above.

Comment: A further question: do you also have `"2013\October Estimates"` and `"2013\September Estimates"` in the same folder?  Do they also need to be processed in the same way?

Comment: @foxidrive, There is only a '2013\November Estimates' folder. The directory was initially set up incorrect. Going forward any new folders and documents will be placed into the correct location as they are completed. This is just a clean up everything to that folder. but because the share drive is 750 GB with who knows how many ppl with access, manually moving is a hassle.

Comment: My God!  It's a simple drag and drop! I have no idea why you want a batch file for a single once-off task, that will take 2 seconds in Explorer.  As for users accessing the files - a batch file will have the same issues.

Comment: @foxidrive, I was hoping to create a batch file to use if/when this problem occurs again. So itll just make all the folders where they are suppose to be and drag and drop everything into the new folders.

Comment: Your details show that the only thing happening is that all files and folders have to be dragged into `\November Estimates` with the exception of one single folder.  That requires control A to mark every folder and file, and control click on the `2012` folder to unmark it, and drag everything else into the `\November Estimates` folder.

Comment: @foxidrive I am very aware of how to drag. I am looking to have a batch command do this because of the sheer volume. There is 600 entities. The entire point of the batch command is so I dont have to manually drag them

Comment: That's not what you said above. Sorry, your explanation of the task has been poor from the beginning and writing code for this little portion will mean coming back and rewriting it when it doesn't do what you want it to do, as you have hidden the scope and full details of task. I attempted to clarify the exact details of the task but...

Comment: @foxidrive, that is exactly what i said? i dont know how more clear i can be. I want to create folders in all of the entity folders (which it currently does), then I want to move all prior documents and folders that were in the entity folders into the newly created folders.

Comment: Sorry for the annoyance.  Your question was so confusing it was hard to see what was being done and where the problem was. It's often not useful to examine code that doesn't work - particularly so when we don't have access to the files that are needed in the code.  In your case I finally see where the issues were, hopefully.

Comment: @foxidrive No worries, I am not annoyed at all. I appreciate any help I can get. I just put the code I have right now up for reference. The purpose of having the entitylist and fundfamily text come up in notepad with the start/wait is so I can manually edit which folders I want to do this in. The manual part of it is something I want. The problem is setting up the command to move what i want

Comment: @foxidrive, as of right now when it goes to create the folders in the entities, the entity list in each fund family comes up in notepad and allows me to remove folders I dont want the new folders being created in. I am just running into syntax errors when it comes to moving the documents, especially the empty folders.

Comment: Did you see the new answer I entered?  What were the error messages when you tried that?

Comment: @foxidrive, see the edit to your provided answer. NEAR PERFECT

Answer (score 0):

regarding the line that produces error, if there're only one folder you want to avoid moving, you can check if the folder to move is not the one:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN (entitylist.txt) DO (
    if "%destdrive%:\%year%\%projections%\%%~a\%%~b\2012" NEQ "%%b" MOVE /Y "%destdrive%:\%year%\%projections%\%%~a\%%~b\%all%" "%destdrive%:\%year%\%projections%\%%~a\%%~b\%year%\%estimates%" 
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately I still am getting "the syntax of the command is incorrect". I am editing my original BAT with your adjustment above.

Comment: Move doesn't have a `/e` switch.

Comment: Hey, this ALMOST does what I was looking for. It moves all the files into the 2013\November Estimates folder BUT, it does not move the other folders and empty folders.

Comment: It's too confusing.  There is not enough information to replicate the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your last loop as you will need a loop to move the folders one by one, and another command to move the files in the main folder.

Perhaps something like this will do it.

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN (entitylist.txt) DO (
    pushd "%destdrive%:\%year%\%projections%\%%~a\%%~b\" && (
    for /d %%c in (*) do if /i not "%%c"=="2012" move "%%c" "%estimates%" 
    move *.* "%estimates%" 
    popd
    )
)
```

This does the following (Im going to use pictures, don't know why i didnt think of that before... -_-

```
CURRENT RESULTS:
```

[image]
[image]

```
DESIRED RESULTS:
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

it basically renames the the `2013` folder in the `entity` and moves everything except 2012 into that folder, which now has the `November Estimates` name

Comment: Thank you. That is near perfect to the layout. I have made edits in my question using your suggested format.

Comment: As we don't have the `fundfamily.txt` and `entitylist.txt` files then we can't reproduce the situation.  But see it the above answer helps.

Comment: This line changes the 2013 and renames it November Estimates, then puts the folders and documents into that folder. see above for a better illustration